# Edges states dispersion relation of gapped graphene

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topology, graphene

I'm currently looking at this paper: [Domain wall in gapped graphene](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.0094.pdf). I do know how to get the dispersion relation of the gapped graphene without the domain wall. But according to this article, it seems possible to derive analytically  the dispersion relation of a infinite gapped graphene with a domain wall at $x=0$.
The schrodinger equation of this system reads:
\begin{equation}
(E-\text{sign}(x) \mu)a_A =t\sum_i b_{A+\vec{s}_i} \quad \text{and} \quad (E+\text{sign}(x) \mu)b_B =t\sum_i a_{B-\vec{s}_i}
\end{equation}

where $a_A$ ($b_B$) are the amplitude on the site of the sublattice A (resp. B).
The vectors $\vec{s_i}$ are just the usual link vectors of the graphene.

My question is the following: how can i get the dispersion relation given in equation (8) and (9-10) of the paper? What the trick?

Edit:
One idea I tried for the bulk dispersion was to square all the equation to get ride of the sign. And then I Fourier Transform the equation. The problem I run into at this point is that I get a sum over all wavevectors that I don't know how to remove...